# Mod rewrite - Dynamic $_GET rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there anyway using ModRewrite to achieve the following:

Initial URL: http://example.com/page?value=test

Rewirted URL: http://example.com/page/value/test

OR

Initial URL: http://example.com/page?value=test&fruit=apple

Rewirted URL: http://example.com/page/value/test?fruit=apple

I need this rule to be dynamic as I don't know all the pages it is going to be used for and I also need to retain the $_GET variables in PHP.

Thanks

Comment: So you receive the URL as http://example.com/page?value=test and need to rewrite it as http://example.com/page/value/test for PHP?  That is backwards from what is normally done.

Comment: I only want to do this to aid SEO but I need to ensure that the $_GET variable still contains all of the values from the original query string

Comment: Still not clear.  Which of these two URLs does your PHP script expect to receive? (additional $_GET vars notwithstanding)

Comment: It's not my speciality, so I may be wrong, but I do not think this methodology will have any positive bearing on SEO. As @Michael mentioned, what you are asking for is really the exact opposite of the normal usage of mod_rewrite rules (and often cited as being done for SEO purposes too).

Comment: Thanks for all your help everyone. Unfortunately things have changed and we don't need to do this anymore!!! Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question makes sense if the URLs in question are stored in the database, and need to be rewritten until the content can be updated to reflect the new URL pattern.   Which, for clarification of the question, would be considered a **redirect** not rewrite, therefore improving SEO.   Then, as the comments above point out, the URL could then be **rewritten** to provide PHP the correct URL parameters. If this what James intended, the config below will help out:

```
### 301 redirect old query string URLs to pretty URLs
### This will help search engines index the new URLs, 
### not ones that are linked in content
### This is rather messy due to the 
### http://example.com/page/value/test?fruit=apple example
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} value=([^&]*)
RewriteRule (.*) /page/value/%1 [R=301,E=rewrite:true]

RewriteCond %{ENV:rewrite} true
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:rewrite} true
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &([^=]*)=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1=%2 [R=301,L]

### Rewrite pretty urls with usable parameters
### [QSA] will maintain extra params such as &fruit=apple
RewriteRule /page/value/(.*) /page.php?value=$1 [QSA]
```

This is messy, but I've run into similar situations where redirecting old URLs stored in the database was necessary until content could be updated.

Hope this helps.